# How to typeset two vertically shifted vectors/smallmatrices

Tags: vertical-alignment

How do I typeset two vectors shifted vertically by half a column height with a scaled line in between? Also, the spacing should preferably not be too large.

[image]

The closest I got so far is

```
$\left.
\raisebox{-0.3ex}{\begin{smallmatrix}a\\a\\s\end{smallmatrix}}
\middle|
raisebox{0.3ex}{\begin{smallmatrix}s\\a\\a\end{smallmatrix}}
\right.$
```

However, Lyx gives me a bunch of errors about missing "$"s, which makes me think I'm not supposed to put a smallmatrix inside a raisebox. Also, the amount of vertical shift is pure guesswork.
Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have basically works, you just need to put `$...$` around the `smallmatrix` environments.

Here is a fancier version that defines a macro for constructing your matrices. The syntax is

```
$\shiftedcolumns{a,a,s}{s,a,a}$
```

This produces what you want:

[image]

The macro accepts columns of arbitrary length, and the lengths on both sides can be different, so something like
`$\shiftedcolumns{a,b,c,d}{d,e,f,g,h}$` is fine:

[image]

Here is the full code:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newcommand\MatrixColumn[1]{%
  \def\sep{\relax\gdef\sep{\\}}% put a \\ between columns
  \begin{smallmatrix}\forcsvlist{\sep}{#1}\end{smallmatrix}%
}
\newcommand\shiftedcolumns[2]{\left.\raisebox{-0.3ex}{$\MatrixColumn{#1}$}\middle|%
                                    \raisebox{0.3ex}{$\MatrixColumn{#2}$}\right.}

\begin{document}
  $\shiftedcolumns{a,a,s}{s,a,a}$

  \bigskip

  $\shiftedcolumns{a,b,c,d}{d,e,f,g,h}$
\end{document}
```

The `\shiftedcolumns` is essentially what you had except that it uses `\MatrixColumn` to typeset the matrix. This is done using a for-loop, `\forcsvloop` from the [etoolbox](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) package, inside a `smallmatrix` command.

Answer (score 1):

Adding the missing `$`s

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
$\left.
\raisebox{-0.3ex}{$\begin{smallmatrix}a\\a\\s\end{smallmatrix}$}
\middle|
\raisebox{0.3ex}{$\begin{smallmatrix}s\\a\\a\end{smallmatrix}$}
\right.$
\end{document}
```

[image]